# choosing random directories in PC using Python

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.x and I don't know how to make my script randomly choose directories in the same PC to copy files.

I want it to copy the files in the random directories. What should I do to make it happen?

```
from sys import argv

import os

import random

script=argv

name=str(script[0])

count = 0

i = 10
while (count < i) :

os.system('start omnomnom.txt')
count+=1

os.mkdir('tembilaland')
os.system(r"copy omnomnom.txt tembilaland")
os.system(r"copy acme.py tembilaland")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing that for... honestly :^)

Well, if you don't have a pre-determined list of target directories, you could use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) then [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one.

Like:

```
# all subdirectories in the user's home
directories = [row[0] for row in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~/subdir'))]
# or if you want to limit to an arbitrary number
directories = []
for i, row in enumerate(os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~'))):
    if i > 100: break
    directories+= [row[0]]

print random.choice(directories)
```

Comment: thanks. i use your code but it didnt work. can you help me fix it?

Comment: Could you elaborate what doesn't work? in which environment you are working, etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a random directory within a folder, you can use the following code:

```
files = os.listdir("path")  # path is the folder path
for f in files:
    if os.path.isdir(f):
       put the directory into an array
```

Lastly, randomly choose the directory from the array. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. but it didnt works. can you try it to make sure it run on your PC?